# cant put any values when referencing a character in a string in assembler for Intel 80386 32-bit

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault, att

basically I want to remove spaces from the text but I get a seg fault and have no idea why.
I used ddd and found that it always breaks at `movb %dl, (%ecx)`. this is the problem.

```
.text
.globl palindrom

palindrom:
pushl %ebp
movl %esp, %ebp
subl $8, %esp

movl 8(%ebp), %eax      #eax and ecx are used to refference individual
movl 8(%ebp), %ecx      #string characters
movl $0, -4(%ebp)       # -4(%ebp) is the counter

razmaci:
movb (%eax), %dl    #both eax and ecx are reffering to the same string
cmpb $0, %dl
je vmsl
cmpb $' ', %dl      #testing to see if the tharacter at eax is ' ' 
je ima_raz
incl %eax
incl %ecx
incl -4(%ebp)
jmp razmaci

ima_raz:
incl %eax         #incrementing eax to move the next string char to where 
movb (%eax), %dl  #the ' ' is
movb %dl, (%ecx)    <-------- THIS IS WHERE IT BREAKS
jmp razmaci     #to causes a seg fault

vmsl:
movl -4(%ebp), %edx
movl $0, %ecx

kraj:
movl %ebp, %esp
popl %ebp
ret
```

Comment: My assembly is a little rusty, but I can see a loop, but I can't see any exit rom the loop.  All jmps return to razmaci

Comment: i just forgot the loop but thats not the problem. the problem is that when i put 'mov anything, (any reg)' i.e. 'movb %dl, (%eax)' that is where it breaks.

Comment: Can you please provide us with a full program? I don't see where your program crashes.

Comment: idk how to do it exactly ill just answer it

Comment: ok i posted the program

Comment: you still have infinite loop, just step over single instruction in debugger. If it does crash during first iteration, your initialization of `eax+ecx` is wrong. If it will work till the end of string, it's crashing because of infinite loop. And you will need to debug it any way, because your algorithm is wrong, so even when you fix the loop termination, it will not work as expected.

Comment: Like Ped7g said, you have too many errors. Time to learn how to use a debugger (which is an invaluable tool to learn any way, specially for assembly).

Comment: so i've edited the code to exit the loop, once again that was not my problem. the problem is that it breaks whenever i try to put smth where eax is pointing. breaks for constants registers, basically anything.

Comment: i rly dont know how to explain this. i am using a debugger and everything is ok EXCEPT for when i try to put something in the place of the space ( `movb %dl, (%ecx)` )

Comment: Do you happen to call this from C/C++? Like `someasmfunction("some string");`?

Comment: yes, from c, here is the code
`#include <stdio.h>

int palindrom (char *str);

int main () {
 char *str = "aNa vol isil OvA na";
 int a = palindrom (str);
 printf ("%s\n%d\n", str, a);
 
 return 0;
}`
the int a is just an indicator for an error its not important

Comment: I would expect any decent C compiler to emit warning over this (losing const-ness of literal)... do `char str[200] = "aNa vol isil OvA na";` to have the string buffer writeable for sure, with some reasonable length for experimenting. You are trying overwriting the string literal, which is immutable. BTW notice how you manage to post twice incomplete source... [MCVE] next time.

Comment: you just saved a whole lot of my hairs from being pulled out my good man. cheers

Comment: Considering you are learning AT&T syntax and intermixing with C/C++, I think I can already welcome you to the not-so-secret club of bald head programmers... cheers.

Answer (score 0):

This might be off by one, but...

```
razmaci:
dec -4(%ebp) # Decrement counter
jz kraj      # Stop at zero

movb (%eax), %dl    #both eax and ecx are reffering to the same string
cmpb $' ', %dl      #testing to see if the tharacter at eax is ' ' 
je ima_raz
incl %eax
incl %ecx
# incl -4(%ebp)
jmp razmaci
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me your initial load of string pointer might be wrong.  Perhaps it should be:

```
movl 12(%ebp), %eax      #eax and ecx are used to refference individual
movl 12(%ebp), %ecx      #string characters
```